# Unexpected error in jabref 4.1 with java

Tags: errors, jabref, java

yesterday I updated my jabref 4.0 to the lastest version, 4.1. However, when I open it appears this window:

[image]

I went to the java webpage and downloaded the Version 8 Update 151 available there, which I thought that could fix the error, but it didn't happen.

There are something else that I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified your Java version (run `java -version` in the command prompt)? It's possible it's picking up an older version.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I did it and the result was

Comment: I did it and the resut was `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)`

Comment: Maybe the JabRef support forum is the more appropriate place for this: They even have a recent http://discourse.jabref.org/t/java-error-on-jabref/974

Comment: Seems this was implemented with https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3310

Comment: Is there any compelling reason for not just using version 4.0? If not, file a bug with JabRef and keep using 4.0 until it is fixed. The JabRef people are quite responsive.

Comment: I had this: it turned out there was a second copy of Java in (I think) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\java`. I zapped it and then had to adjust the PATH to get the correct one to pick up. All that said, the question is off-topic for us: needs Windows/Java/... expertise, not TeX knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Unfortunately, version 4.0 has the same requirements and will have problems with lower Java version. We just added the Java check in version 4.1, because so many people were reporting issues that boiled down to old Java runtimes. If you really want to use an older Java version, you will have to stick with JabRef 3.8.2.

Answer (score 6):

We just improved the error message to also include the path of the old Java installation. So you should now have enough information to locate and remove the old installation.

The improvement is included in the most recent [development version of JabRef](https://builds.jabref.org/master/) and will be released as part of 4.2.